# Puppeteer browser download failed

Tags: puppeteer

So basically I'm just starting out with puppeteer.js. My systems seems unable to npm install the library correctly. Here is what I did:

1. Make new directory
2. Navigate to said directory in bash
3. `npm init -y`
4. `npm install puppeteer`

After doing those steps I get a error message exactly like this

```
$ npm i puppeteer

> puppeteer@20.7.1 postinstall C:\Users\neilj\Desktop\puppeteer2\node_modules\puppeteer
> node install.js

Browser download failed C:\Users\neilj\Desktop\puppeteer2\node_modules\@puppeteer\browsers\lib\cjs\launch.js:48
    options.platform ??= (0, detectPlatform_js_1.detectBrowserPlatform)();
                     ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\neilj\Desktop\puppeteer2\node_modules\@puppeteer\browsers\lib\cjs\main.js:19:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for puppeteer@20.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=16.3.0"} (current: {"node":"14.17.5","npm":"6.14.14"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: puppeteer@20.7.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for puppeteer-core@20.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=16.3.0"} (current: {"node":"14.17.5","npm":"6.14.14"})    
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: puppeteer-core@20.7.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @puppeteer/browsers@1.4.1: wanted: {"node":">=16.3.0"} (current: {"node":"14.17.5","npm":"6.14.14"})npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @puppeteer/browsers@1.4.1
npm WARN puppeteer2@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN puppeteer2@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

I was wondering if anyone else had come across this error since I cannot seem to find another thread that had this particular issue

I'm basically just trying to get this code installed so I can work with it in the first place. Im intending to get some insight if anyone has any. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me because I was using Node v14 and puppeteer v20. You'll need Node v15 for puppeteer v20 or puppeteer < v20 with Node v14.

> **Note:** Node v14 supports `??` but not `??=` which is supported after Node v15 ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment#browser_compatibility))